# Argparse - Custom Action update to an dest dict

Tags: python, argparse

I want to collect some options as a dict using `argparse`. I have wrote a custom Action class as follows. The problem is that the `__call__` method is never invoked.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

class UpdateDict(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, nargs=None, **kwargs):
        print('UpdateDict', option_strings, dest, nargs)
        if nargs != 1:
            raise ValueError("nargs must be 1")
        super(UpdateDict, self).__init__(option_strings, dest, nargs=nargs, **kwargs)
        print(self)

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        print('%r %r %r' % (namespace, values, option_string))
        dest = getattr(namespace, self.dest)
        print(dest)
        key = option_string[1]
        dest.update(key = values[0])

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='formula alpha')
    parser.add_argument('formula', nargs=1, type=str, help='alpha formula')
    parser.set_defaults(mydict={})

    parser.add_argument('-a', '--alpha', nargs=1, type=str, default=['alas'], action=UpdateDict, dest='mydict')
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--beta', nargs=1, type=int, default=[0], action=UpdateDict, dest='mydict')

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                                                                                                                        
    args = parse_args()
    print(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `parse_args` function need to return the parser which it creates, as you need its `parse_args` method for the actual parsing.  Also, you should source the arguments from `sys.argv[1:]`, basically the arguments except for the main program's argument (i.e. your script name).  So you should rename `parse_args` to a more appropriate name.  An incomplete example:

```
def make_parser():
    # your ArgumentParser construction code ...
    return parser

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    parser = make_parser()
    parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

Do note that you have some minor issues with your implementation of your Action which you will need to fix.  When I threw all your code (with the `return parser` added) on the `ArgumentParser` that your code constructed, this was the issue:

```
>>> parser.parse_known_args(['-b', '1'])
Namespace(formula=None, mydict=['alas']) [1] '-b'
['alas']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/argparse.py", line 1769, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/argparse.py", line 1975, in _parse_known_args
    start_index = consume_optional(start_index)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/argparse.py", line 1915, in consume_optional
    take_action(action, args, option_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/argparse.py", line 1843, in take_action
    action(self, namespace, argument_values, option_string)
  File "<stdin>", line 13, in __call__
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Answer (score 0):

With your script, simplified to focus on putting values in `mydict`:

```
import argparse

class UpdateDict(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        adict = getattr(namespace, 'mydict')
        adict.update({self.dest: values})

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.set_defaults(mydict={})
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--alpha', default='alas', action=UpdateDict)
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--beta', type=int, default=0, action=UpdateDict)
    return parser.parse_args()  # parse and return

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                                                                                                                        
    args = parse_args()
    print(args)
```

I get

```
2333:~/mypy$ python3 stack39263156.py
Namespace(alpha='alas', beta=0, mydict={})
2337:~/mypy$ python3 stack39263156.py -a one
Namespace(alpha='alas', beta=0, mydict={'alpha': 'one'})
2337:~/mypy$ python3 stack39263156.py -a one -b 2
Namespace(alpha='alas', beta=0, mydict={'beta': 2, 'alpha': 'one'})
```

You can restore the `nargs=1` test if you want, but the default `None` implies 1 argument.  Most don't use `nargs=1`. It makes sure the value is a single element list; most people want multiple element lists (e.g. '+' or '*' nargs).

I like your use of `set_defaults` to put `mydict` in the namespace.  I then  retrieve it from the namespace, and update it, using the argument's `dest` as the `key`.  Your version confuses the `dest`, and overwrite the `mydict` attribute.

The default `store_action` uses `setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)`, to do the same thing, but with the namespace object rather than the embedded `mydict`.

The usual defaults handling fills the `alpha` and `beta` attributes (the `dest`).  To put those in `mydict` instead, you'd have to use something like

```
parser.set_defaults(mydict={'alpha':'alas', 'beta':0})
```

`SUPPRESS` can be used to keep defaults out of the usual `dest` attributes

```
parser.add_argument('-a', '--alpha', action=UpdateDict, default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
parser.add_argument('-b', '--beta', type=int, action=UpdateDict)
```

the no-argument run would produce:

```
2347:~/mypy$ python3 stack39263156.py
Namespace(beta=None, mydict={'beta': 0, 'alpha': 'alas'})
```

The use of an embedded dictionary is an interesting idea, though I'm not sure what it adds.  `vars(args)` is recommended as a way of turning a `namespace` into a dictionary.

```
{'mydict': {'alpha': 'one', 'beta': 2}, 'beta': None}
```